# Setting dark or light theme of application by user choice (Android)

Tags: android, android-theme, android-background

We are applying dark and light themes to an app. Our original theme is going to be light. In this situation I have a problem changing the real transition color of an activity. While switching between activities, I apply an animation using this code:

```
finish();
startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
```

This leaves a background that we set on the application theme on the **manifest** that goes like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/MyStyle_Light" />
```

where the styles are something like this:

```
<style android:name="MyStyle_Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
     <!-- some style resources -->
</style>

<style android:name"MyStyle_Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
     <!-- some style resources -->
</style>
```

Now, the style **Theme.AppCompat.Light** has a light background on its window. It is defined within the activity from **AndroidManifest.xml**.

To change an activity's theme I use a code like this, and it works **after seeing the original color that comes from the manifest at the very first opening.**

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    setTheme(R.style.MyStyle_Dark); // can also be MyStyle_Light depending on user choice
    super.onCreate();
    setContentView(R.layout.MyLayout);

    // rest goes on
}
```

The problem lies on the original color that appears after the fade-out and fade-in animation, because even if user chooses the dark theme, since **MyStyle_Light** is on manifest theme, they always see a light background on the fade out animation.

How can I change the background color that comes from the manifest?

Things I've tried or thought so far:

1. Using "android:windowBackground" which doesn't work,
2. Setting the theme **on the application class** without using a theme in manifest which also didn't work.
3. Using an attribute on the manifest to change styles at runtime from .xml which I don't think will work since there is nothing to refer to. (Just tried, it doesn't work.)
4. Using a duplicate activity with different theme resource attached to the manifest and starting it depending on user choice (seems unnecessary to me)

Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks.